# How to use regex in html5 attribute for Cyrillic letters?

Tags: regex, html

First I've searched for the answer but with no success till now.

I have an form that submits some inputs via POST but before that I want to secure on client side that for the First Name and Last Name are used only Latin or Cyrillic letters.

So far it works only for the Latin letters but I cant get it work with Cyrillic letters.
This is what I use now, any help would be appreciated

```
<input id="userfnamesignup" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3-30}" 
       name="user_fname" placeholder="Enter your name please" required />
```

Comment: Some valid cyrillic names contain non-letter symbols, e.g. "Анна-Мария" or "Иван-Асен". Those are valid first names that won't match your pattern, just like "Jean-Claude" won't.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your regular expression. `{3-30}` should be `{3,30}`. Adding `а-я` within the `[]` should work. If not, the answer below would work.

Comment: @PhistucK `а-я` would exclude lots of letters like `љ` which are valid in some Cyrillic scripts.

Comment: @lanzz - right, the point was that the syntax error probably prevented the code from working when al1en tried anything. Searching the UNICODE table for the first and last character would do the job regarding Cyrillic characters only (not for punctuation, as you mentioned).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript support for unicode is not great, but you should be able to use the [Cyrillic unicode character range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) as part of the regex and it should work.

```
[a-zA-Z\u0400-\u04ff]{3,30}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7anQs/

Comment: I tryed it works, thanks Ill mark as answer in 4 mins. Also if you can tell me on PHP side how to filter phone number in this format (+nnn nn nnn-nnn)??

Comment: @al1en ask a separate question

Answer (score 0):

Update on the answer from Explosion Pills to accept whitespaces

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z\u0400-\u04ff\s]{3,30}"
```